# SELinux restorecon

Tags: samba, selinux

I am trying to export a Samba share and changing its SELinux fcontext to 'samba_share_t'. However in the guide that I follow after changing the fcontext, I need to run 'restorecon' over the exported samba directory. Looking at the manpage for it => "restore file(s) default SELinux security contexts", I am just wondering is not that going to revert back the directory to a state where fcontext does not have the 'samba_share_t' value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you modified the context to something different than is in the installed policy, it will set the context according to the policy.

Answer (score 0):

According to Red Hat documentation ([Persistent Changes: semanage fcontext](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/index#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext)), if you want these to persist you'd use `semanage`, then a `restorecon` will use what you want instead of the policy's context.